# How do I prevent this image from shaking/vibrating when hovered

Tags: html, css

I would like the container width and height to increase whilst the image remains unaffected. In other words I'd like the image to stop shaking when hovering over the container.
I have tried formatting the width, positioning and the object fit properties but nothing seems to work. It's so frustrating, I need help.

Thank you in advance.

Here's the HTML code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Hanyi;
  src: url(/HanyiSentyBrushSong.ttf);
}

 :root {
  --my-font: Hanyi;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.image-container {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #262626;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: center;
}

.image-container:hover {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  transform-origin: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="/Ny mapp/destiny-ayodele-0xdWoqxoF_Q-unsplash.jpg" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a link or example code here

Comment: It's in the question

Comment: @Chessman Where in the question then? Can't see a link, and your code isn't a working snippet...

Comment: Running your snippet (with an image of my own) on Edge/Windows 10 everything looks fine. On hover the parent expands but the image stays as it is, no shaking. What browser and OS/device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to remove

```
.image-container:hover {
    width: 350px;
    height: 450px;
    transform-origin: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}  

/* Comment These Out */
.image-container {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #262626;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

And add

```
.image-container::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #262626;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: -1;
}

.image-container:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

## Demo

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Hanyi;
  src: url(/HanyiSentyBrushSong.ttf);
}

:root {
  --my-font: Hanyi;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.image-container {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: none;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-container::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #262626;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0px 0px;
}

.image-container:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="/Ny mapp/destiny-ayodele-0xdWoqxoF_Q-unsplash.jpg" alt="image">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This increases the size of the image along with its container which the OP did not want.

Comment: But it doesn't work regardless as the image is still shaking. You might need to zoom in to clearly see what I mean

Comment: edited according to OP's requirements